# Onclick submit form not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

Form submit code using onclick.

I have a form submit code using onclick, this code can run well with firefox but when using chrome this code can't work.

`echo '<option onClick="document.formname.stts2.value=\''.$i.'\';document.formname.submit();"  value="'.$i.'"> '.$Name[$i].'</option>';`

Comment: You should not use a click handler on an option element, there are issues with browser support. Use a change handler on the select field.

Comment: Yesterday, I tried it like that but what happened was that all the forms I used were updated even though the form names were different.

Comment: Then you must have done something wrong in targeting the right form. Can't tell you what that might be though, without a proper example.